# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number on query

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble getting a number instead of a string in my query. I have two tables and a pivot table.

**File**:

- id
- name
- document
- language

**Role**:

- id
- name (admin, partner, dealer, associate)

**File_role**:

- id
- file_id
- role_id

I want to display all the files for the 'dealer' role so i tried this:

```
$file_role = File_Role::where('role_id', '=', $id)->get('file_id');
$file = File::where('id', '=', $file_role)->get();
dd($file_role);
```

However it keeps returning errors on:

```
$file = File::where('id', '=', $file_role)->get();
```

The error is:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number.

The query below that is:

```
select * from `file` where `id` = {"file_id":1}.
```

Any ideas how I can get a number instead of `"file_id":1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to use `whereIn`:

```
$file_role = File_Role::where('role_id', '=', $id)->pluck('file_id');
$file = File::whereIn('id', $file_role)->get();
```

Other than just solving your issue I think there's some more things you can consider here:

`File_Role` seems to be a pivot table model. Generally you should not have these models as models in your app but rather define relationships for example in your `File.php` model file:

```
public function role() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

This way your code becomes the (arguably) more readable:

```
$file = File::whereHas('role', fn ($query) => $query->where('id', $id));
```

This will result in all files that have a role with id given by `$id`

More on [many to many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score 3):

You can give this a try. Here you get the first result and then get the file_id from that model.

```
$file_role = File_Role::where('role_id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
$file = File::where('id', '=', $file_role->file_id)->get();

dump($file_role);
dd($file);
```

Comment: this indeed works. but this only returns 1 object, in this case i have to get multiple 'files'

Comment: The line ``$file = File::where('id', '=', $file_role->file_id)->get();`` returns multiple results if there are multiple files with the given 'id' (should only be 1 as id should be unique). 

Not sure if this is what you need but you can try this:

``
$file_role = File_Role::where('role_id', '=', $id)->get();
$file = File::whereIn('id', '=', $file_role->pluck('file_id'))->get();
``